# call observer for contact us page data save

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer, contact-us

I have used below code to save contact us page data.but it's not working.

```
<events>
<controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
<observers>
    <freedom_customercontact_controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
        <class>freedom_customercontact/observer</class>
        <method>controllerActionPostdispatchContactsIndexPost</method>
    </freedom_customercontact_controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
</observers>
```

Observer code

```
 <?php

class Freedom_Customercontact_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionPostdispatchContactsIndexPost()
    {
        exit('Hi');
        $data = $observer->getData();
    $post = $data['controller_action']->getRequest()->getPost();
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me why this not working please.

Comment: one good solution create your observer and use in when user press submit button of contact us page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found solution event is in front end tag not in global

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
            <observers>
                <freedom_customercontact_controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>customercontact/observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPostdispatchContactsIndexPost</method>
                </freedom_customercontact_controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_contacts_index_post>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: lol...............

Comment: @Freedom please tick your answer as the solution